# Testing hooks which throw errors

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

The [deprecated?] `react-hooks-testing-library` would return any errors thrown by the hook under test.

Probably my misunderstanding, but it looks like implementation now in the main `@testing-library/react` lost this feature?

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
import { safeRenderHook } from './safeRenderHook';

function useFail() {
  throw 'fail';
}

function useSucceed() {
  return 'success';
}

it('should fail', () => {
  const { result, error } = safeRenderHook(() => useFail());
  expect(error.current).toEqual('fail');
  expect(result.current).toBeUndefined();
});

it('should succeed', () => {
  const { result, error } = safeRenderHook(() => useSucceed());
  expect(result.current).toEqual('success');
  expect(error.current).toBeUndefined();
});
```

... and maybe an implementation like this?

````
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

/**
 * A variant of `renderHook()` which returns `{ result, error }` with `error`
 * being set to any errors thrown by the hook. Otherwise, it behaves the same as
 * `renderHook()`.
 *
 * ```
 * const useFail = () => Promise.reject('fail!');
 *
 * it('should fail') {
 *  const { error } = safeRenderHook(() => useFail());
 *  expect(error).toEqual('fail!');
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * >Note: since this effectively swallows errors, you should be sure to
 * explicitly check the returned `error` value.
 */
export function safeRenderHook(renderCallback, options = {}) {
  const { initialProps = [], wrapper } = options;
  const result = React.createRef();
  const error = React.createRef();

  function TestComponent({ hookProps }) {
    let pendingError;
    let pendingResult;

    try {
      pendingResult = renderCallback(...hookProps);
    } catch (err) {
      pendingError = err;
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      result.current = pendingResult;
      error.current = pendingError;
    });

    return null;
  }

  const { rerender: baseRerender, unmount } = render(<TestComponent hookProps={initialProps} />, { wrapper });

  function rerender(rerenderCallbackProps) {
    return baseRerender(<TestComponent hookProps={rerenderCallbackProps} />);
  }

  return { result, error, rerender, unmount };
}
````

ps: I actually made a type-safe version of this if anyone's interested - but the type annotations make the example a bit harder to read on SO.

Comment: If a hook is throwing an error it's actually quite hard to use it. To catch that error you need to wrap it tin a conditional (try/catch) thus violating rules of hooks. I'we encounter a similar issue in our code base and decided to rewrite the hook to handle error instead of throwing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jest you could do:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react'

function useFail() {
  throw new Error('Oops')
}

it('should throw', () => {
  expect(() => {
    renderHook(() => useFail())
  }).toThrow(Error('Oops'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using expect.toThrow did not help me either. The hook is rendered multiple times (not sure why) and then exits without an error.

Following this [comment](https://github.com/testing-library/testing-library-docs/issues/1060#issuecomment-1466714000), I was able to solve the issue with:

*vitest-setup.js*

```js
const suppressConsoleError = () => {
    const errorSpy = vi.spyOn(console, "error")
        .mockImplementation(() => {
            //do nothing
        });

    return () => errorSpy.mockRestore();
};

global.renderHookWithError = (...args) => {
    let error;
    const restore = suppressConsoleError();

    try {
        renderHook(...args);
    } catch (ex) {
        error = ex;
    }

    restore();
    throw error;
};
```

*myhook.js*

```
export default useMyHook = (var) => {

  if (!var) {
     throw new Error("no var");
  }

  ...
};
```

*myhook.test.js*

```js
   it("should throw", () => {
     expect(() => {
        renderHookWithError(useMyHook);
      }).toThrow("no var");

   });
```