# I need to render a custom hook and test the error message when someone tries to use the hook without the provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Using React, Jest and react testing library

My custom hook

```
import { useContext } from "react";

import { SelectThemeContext } from "../contexts/SelectThemeContext/SelectThemeContextProvider";

import { isEmpty } from "../utils/functions/isEmpty";

const useSelectThemeContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(SelectThemeContext);

  if (isEmpty(context)) {
    throw Error(
      "You have to use useSelectThemeContext inside <SelectThemeContextProvider />",
    );
  }

  const { theme, toggleTheme } = context;
  return { theme, toggleTheme };
};

export default useSelectThemeContext;
```

My test

```
it("[ACAMP-03] - should return error message when trying to use custom hook without provider", async () => {
    let message: string;
    try {
      await renderHook(() => useSelectThemeContext());
      message = "";
    } catch (e: any) {
      message = e.message;
    }

    expect(message).toEqual(
      "You have to use useSelectThemeContext inside <SelectThemeContextProvider />",
    );
  });
```

I can get the message but I also get an error in the console.

at VirtualConsole. (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:70:28)
at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)

```
console.error
  The above error occurred in the <TestComponent> component:
  
      at TestComponent (C:\Users\rafael.almeida\Documents\Projects\Estudo\acamp\base-reactv18-eslint-prettier-config\node_modules\@testing-library\react\dist\pure.js:281:5)
  
  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
  Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

  at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18687:23)
  at update.callback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18720:5)
  at callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13923:12)
  at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13944:9)
  at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23391:13)
  at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24688:9)  
  at commitLayoutEffects_begin (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
```

**Run test CodeSandBox**
[Test CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-architecture-q3365e?file=/src/useSelectedThemeContext.spec.js)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It's ok, you can leave it, thank you

Comment: It's not about what I can do, it's about what you must do to keep the question on the site. The error message must be in text.

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly, I thanked you for the warning you gave me, I will remove the image and insert it in text, thank you very much again.

Comment: added an answer that worked for me, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77296248/107976

Answer (score 1):

You can/should use [@testing-library/react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-hooks). It provides a different renderHook method that can accept a wrapper parameter, and can return errors.

Your test would then look something like this. I don't believe it has to be async. If your specific requirements require an async function, then refer to the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous). I remember this was a bit different than what I expected for testing async.

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";

it("[ACAMP-03] - should return error message when trying to use custom hook without provider", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useSelectedThemeContext());

    expect(result.error?.message).toEqual(
      "You have to use useSelectThemeContext inside <SelectThemeContextProvider />",
    );
  });
```

If you want to test the functionality with the provider you can do something like this.

```
it("does what the hook is supposed to do", () => {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <SelectedThemeContextProvider>
            {children}
        </SelectedThemeContextProvider>
    );

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useSelectedThemeContext(), {wrapper});

    expect(result.error).toBeUndefined();

    // using color as an example
    expect(result.color).toEqual("#ffffff");
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work for me, I'm using React v18, I read in the documentation that from @testing-library/react-hooks that this will be released in official PR, I couldn't install the package in the project, complicated.. .

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, Ah I apologize, I have been using React 17 until the dust settles and there is widespread support for React 18.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using a means to suppress the console.error specifically for testing, if the algorithm is designed for a way to not need to use this please...

```
const spyConsole = jest
  .spyOn(console, "error")
  .mockImplementation(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test and cover the error handling line by mocking the **useContext** return.

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';

import { useSelectThemeContext} from '../your-path';

describe('useSelectThemeContext', () => {
  it("[ACAMP-03] - should return error message when trying to use custom hook without provider", () => {
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(() => null)
    try {
      renderHook(useSelectThemeContext);
    }
    catch (error) {
      expect(error).toEqual(new Error("You have to use useSelectThemeContext inside <SelectThemeContextProvider />"))
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1089#issuecomment-1175429712_) issue that `renderHook` for React 18 should be imported from `@testing-library/react` which does not expose the `result.error` property like the one exported from `@testing-library/react-hooks`. And there is another [issue](https://github.com/testing-library/testing-library-docs/issues/1060#issuecomment-1466714000) that seems to be stalled since they are requiring a documented API before agreeing to build this functionality back in. So for now here is what I'm doing in order to catch the error and not console.error the expected error:

```
it('should error with message', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});
  try {
    renderHook(() => failingHook());
  } catch (error) {
    expect((error as Error).message).toEqual('Expected error');
  }
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```